# Question about a part in Polya's Theorem

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

I think I have already wasted too much time thinking about this, so bear with me. I have a question about a specific step in Polya's Theorem I can't seem to find a simple solution to. For reference I'm attaching the source.
[image: Theorem]
[image: Solution]

The bit I don't quite grasp is the part at the end:

"Thus $\int_C \cdots \neq 0$, since there is exactly one non-zero term."

I see that the highest order pole at $\infty$ of $h(z)^\kappa z^{r'-\kappa r}$ is $z^{r'}$ and thus the integral is non-zero by definition. Every other term of the form $z^m$ for $m<r'$ evaluates to zero, because of the definition. Similarly for the terms with poles at $p_k$. The problem I have is that the definition of $r'$ and $s_k'$ only takes care of the "pure integrals", while there also appear mixed terms. Such a term, for example, would be
$$\int_C f(z) h(z)^N z^{r'-r} \left(\frac{q_k}{z-p_k}\right)^{s_k} \, {\rm d}z = 0 \, ,$$
but I think that is non-obvious. Surely, each factor $z^{r'-r}$ and $\left(\frac{q_k}{z-p_k}\right)^{s_k}$ individually evaluates to zero, but for the product?

I figured that one approach would be to make use of the definition of $N$ and the fact that these zero-integrals hold for every $n\geq N$. To simplify matters, let's for moment call $x_0,x_1,...,x_l$ the collection of terms in $h(z)$ for the different types of poles, so $h(z)=x_0+x_1+...+x_l$. We know that
$$\int_C f(z) h(z)^N h(z)^m \, {\rm d}z = 0 \tag{0}$$
for all $m\geq 0$. If $m\leq \kappa$, then
$$\int_C f(z) h(z)^N x_k^m \, {\rm d}z = 0$$
for $k=0,1,...,l$. Hence I thought a term of the form e.g. $x_0^a x_1^{m-a}$ could be deduced from
$$h^m + h^{m-1}\sum_{k=0}^l c_{1,k} x_k + h^{m-2}\sum_{k=0}^l c_{2,k} x_k^2 + ... + h\sum_{k=0}^l c_{m-1,k} x_k^{m-1}$$
knowing that the integral over this expression vanishes. But the number of adjustable coefficients are only $(m-1)(l+1)$, so for $m=3$ and $l=2$ this is $6$, while third degree possibilities(monomials) contained in $h^3$ are $x_0x_1x_2$ and $x_ix_j^2$ for $i=0,1,2$ and two choices for $j$ for each $i$ which are 6, so in total $7$ there are not enough constants.

I'd appreciate any input.

Answer (score 0):

I guess I have found a way; correct me if I'm wrong.
We do know
$$\oint_C f(z) h(z)^N z^m = 0 \qquad \forall m < r'$$
$$\oint_C f(z) h(z)^N \left(\frac{q_k}{z-p_k}\right)^m = 0 \qquad \forall m < s_k', k=1,...,l \, .$$
As for the case
$$\oint_C f(z) h(z)^N h(z)^\kappa z^{r'-\kappa r} \neq 0$$
with $r'-\kappa r\leq r$, expanding $h(z)^\kappa z^{r'-\kappa r}$ gives rise to terms of the form
$$z^m \left(\frac{q_{1}}{z-p_{1}}\right)^{m_1} \left(\frac{q_{2}}{z-p_{2}}\right)^{m_2} \cdots \left(\frac{q_{l}}{z-p_{l}}\right)^{m_l} \tag{1}$$
with $0 \leq m_k \leq \kappa s_{k}<s_k'$ ($1\leq k\leq l$) and $r'-\kappa r \leq m \leq r'$ with $m=r'$ only if $m_k=0$ for all $k$. Therefore and wlog we can assume $m_{1} \geq m_{2} \geq ... \geq m_{l} \geq 0$ with $m<r'$. With the expansion about $z=p_1$
$$z^m \left(\frac{q_{2}}{z-p_{2}}\right)^{m_2} \cdots \left(\frac{q_{l}}{z-p_{l}}\right)^{m_l} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty c_{1,n} \left(\frac{z-p_{1}}{q_{1}}\right)^{n} \tag{2} \, ,$$
we can re-write (1) as
$$z^m \left(\frac{q_{1}}{z-p_{1}}\right)^{m_1} \left(\frac{q_{2}}{z-p_{2}}\right)^{m_2} \cdots \left(\frac{q_{l}}{z-p_{l}}\right)^{m_l} = \left(\frac{q_{1}}{z-p_{1}}\right)^{m_1}\sum_{n=0}^{m_1} c_{1,n} \left(\frac{z-p_{1}}{q_{1}}\right)^{n} \\
+ \left(\frac{q_{1}}{z-p_{1}}\right)^{m_1} \left[ z^m \left(\frac{q_{2}}{z-p_{2}}\right)^{m_2} \cdots \left(\frac{q_{l}}{z-p_{l}}\right)^{m_l} - \sum_{n=0}^{m_1} c_{1,n} \left(\frac{z-p_{1}}{q_{1}}\right)^{n} \right] \, .$$
Upon integration, the first term on the RHS evaluates to zero by definition. The second term is now regular at $z=p_1$, but may still have singularities at $p_2,...,p_l$ and $\infty$. Effectively re-expanding the second term in a laurent-series about $z=p_2$, the principal part is eliminated upon integration, since its order is $m_2\leq \kappa s_2$ and we are left with the remainder, whose analytic continuation may have poles at $p_3,...,p_l$ and $\infty$. Repeating the argument, we can eliminate the principal parts of the laurent-expansion about $p_3,...,p_l$ and the final remainder must be a polynomial of degree $m<r'$ in $z$, since the order at $\infty$ is $m$.